# How to switch camera to its starting position again?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello guys well I am trying to switch camera according to my game view here what i wanted is first my MainCam1 will switch to cam2 after that when pin settled is complete then it should switch back to Maincam1 and this should be in loop whenever action is made.
I will be thankful for your help

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class PinCounter : MonoBehaviour {
    public Text standingDisplay;
    private GameManager gameManager;
    private bool ballOutOfPlay = false;
    private int lastStandingCount = -1;
    private int lastSettledCount = 10;
    private float lastChangeTime;
    public Camera Maincam1;
    public Camera cam2;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Maincam1.enabled = true;
        cam2.enabled = false;
        gameManager = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<GameManager> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        standingDisplay.text = CountStanding ().ToString ();

        if (ballOutOfPlay) {
            UpdateStandingCountAndSettle();
            standingDisplay.color = Color.red;
            Maincam1.enabled = false;
            cam2.enabled = true;
        }
    }

    public void Reset () {
        lastSettledCount = 10;
    }

    void OnTriggerExit (Collider collider) {
        if (collider.gameObject.name == "Ball") {
            ballOutOfPlay = true;
        }
    }

    void UpdateStandingCountAndSettle () {
        // Update the lastStandingCount
        // Call PinsHaveSettled() when they have
        int currentStanding = CountStanding ();
        cam2.enabled = false;
        Maincam1.enabled = true;
        if (currentStanding != lastStandingCount) {
            lastChangeTime = Time.time;
            lastStandingCount = currentStanding;

            return;
        }

        float settleTime = 0.3f;  // How long to wait to consider pins settled
        if ((Time.time - lastChangeTime) > settleTime) { // If last change > 3s ago
            PinsHaveSettled();


        }

    }

    void PinsHaveSettled () {
        int standing = CountStanding ();
        int pinFall = lastSettledCount - standing;
        lastSettledCount = standing;

        gameManager.Bowl (pinFall);


        lastStandingCount = -1; // Indicates pins have settled, and ball not back in box
        ballOutOfPlay = false;
        standingDisplay.color = Color.green;


    }

    int CountStanding () {
        int standing = 0;

        foreach (Pin pin in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Pin>()) {
            if (pin.IsStanding()) {
                standing++;

            }
        }

        return standing;
    }
    void LateUpdate(){

    }
}
```

Comment: And what is a problem? Do you  have any errors or does your code not work?

Answer (score 0):

Add these variables to the top of your class:

```
Vector3 cam1StartPos;
Vector3 cam2StartPos;
```

Then put this in `Start ()`:

```
cam1StartPos = Maincam1.gameObject.transform.position;
cam2StartPos = cam2.gameObject.transform.position;
```

Then whenever you want to reset the position of either camera, you have the start position handy.

Comment: But in your code there is no frame update actually camera is switching to cam2 but what i wanted is that cam2 has to change to Maincam1 also

Comment: Can you rephrase your issue?